# Plugin or script to apply updated media settings to all featured images

Tags: theme-development, media-settings

I need to know if there exists a script or plugin that will add a button the "Settings > Media Settings" that will rebuild all thumbnails to match the current media size settings.

The problem this seeks to solve is when the site owner decides he/she would like different thumbnail and featured image sizes after having uploaded several at the wordpress default settings of 150px, 300px, 1200px

This solution would allow users to auto resize the images in one click to match the current settings.

Comment: I guess that's why plugin recommendation was made off-topic, both answers bellow are valid, which to choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I install [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) on pretty much every single website I build. It does exactly what you need and I've never had a single problem with it.

You can either resize them all at once in bulk through a tools submenu, or you can do individual ones in the media library.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Image Sizes is a plugin that I'm using on a project right now, it has been very nice for many reasons, including the ability to do a one-click thumbnail regeneration!

[Here's the plugin page.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-image-sizes/)